# sorting a datetime jqGrid column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In my jqGrid I have a column that displays dates in the format

```
29-11-1973 05:46:40
```

I've defined this column like so in the column model

```
colModel :[
    // other columns defined here         
    {name: 'timeCol', sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'd-m-Y H:i:s'}
]
```

But they are not sorted when I click on the column heading. I'm using jqGrid v 4.5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `datefmt` is very rudimentary. How you can read in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) it supports only "/", "-" and "." as separators and `d`, `m`, `Y` with small variation. One can't use DataTime format. So the option `datefmt` will be not used typically at all.

Instead of that one should use [formatter: "date"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types). It convert input data into `Date` JavaScript objects. Such objects can be easy sorted. One should use `formatoptions` to inform `formatter: "date"` about the source format and the format in which one need to display the date in the grid. Typically it's enough to specify `srcformat` and `newformat` in `formatoptions`. Both will have the same value `"d-m-Y H:i:s"` in your case. So the solution will be to use

```
{name: "timeCol", sorttype: "date", formatter: "date",
    formatoptions: {srcformat: "d-m-Y H:i:s", newformat: "d-m-Y H:i:s"}}
```